# неудовлетворяющий вывод при использовании цикла for со списками на Python

Tags: python, циклы

окей, если я записываю

```
s= ["a", "b", "c"]
f=["aa","bb","cc"]
all_thing=[]
for s in s:
    s=s.upper()
    all_thing.append(s)
for f in f:
    all_thing.append(f)
    print(all_thing)
```

то мне выдает:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'aa']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'aa', 'bb']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

а по сути должно быть `['A', 'B', 'C', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']`

подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: `res = [x.upper() for x in s] + f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s= ["a", "b", "c"]
f=["aa","bb","cc"]
all_thing=[]
for s in s:
    s=s.upper()
    all_thing.append(s)
for f in f:
    all_thing.append(f)
print(all_thing) # отступ в этой строке надо убрать
```

У вас просто `print` три раза выполняется